# intent-filter is not allowed?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, intentfilter, mobile-development

I'm getting an `"Element intent-filter is not allowed here"` error. The instructions were to simply cut and paste the intent filter from `WeatherActivity` to `MainMenuActivity` since `WeatherActivity` was created first but it doesn't like it when I do it. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.introandroidapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IntroAndroidApp">

        <activity
            android:name=".MyDrawing"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenuActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name=".WeatherActivity"
            android:exported="true">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<intent-filter>` should be inside `activity` tag. If you want to mark `MainMenuActivity` as main, try something like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainMenuActivity"
        android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Don't forget that the `main` activity should have `exported="true"`.